# inkwell onTap is not working inside container

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to make a gallery app. i want a picture to open individually when tapped. but when I tap on a picture inkwell animation occurs but the new page doesn't open. i have defined second page in routes
Here is the code of landing page

```
class _ImageViewState extends State<ImageView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: PhotoView(
          maxScale: 600.0,
          minScale: 200.0,
          imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/mountain1.jpg",),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the code where I'm calling the above class

```
child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () => {const ImageView()},
                        child: Image.asset('assets/mountain1.jpg', fit: BoxFit.fill,)),
```

Comment: If your ImageView() is a new page that'll appear when tap the InkWell, then you need to use [Navigator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html). Follow the example on the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

Comment: what is this `ImageView()` ? can you provide snippet code

Comment: your ImageView() is the stateful widget that has a method createState() to create your _ImageViewState in your code snippet. And you're currently calling it in the onTap function. If you don't know how it is created, then I think you should read about [Stateful](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) and [Stateless](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html) widget.

Comment: i was trying to navigate to ImageView page which displays the image, but i was not using Navigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside

> OnTap method

you can only add functionality things, you can't load widget like that. if you try to load.

Or please provide more information here.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can open new page

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ImageView()),
);
```